# Can't authenticate deploy of Databricks bundle in Azure pipeline using service principal

Tags: azure-pipelines, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-asset-bundle

**Issue**
Trying to deploy a Databricks bundle within an Azure pipeline.

- Databricks CLI = v0.209.0
- Bundle artifact is downloaded to the vm correctly.  Conducted via these instructions: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/ci-cd/ci-cd-azure-devops)
- Service principal is being used for authentication.  It's access is verified by its ability to provision a databricks workspace in Terraform.  Also, its credentials are sufficient to generate a Microsoft Entra ID
- The task I am trying to authenticate is `databricks bundle deploy`

**Approaches**
Attempted to set a .databrickscfg file using the default syntax. Using an Entra ID as the token, I attempted

```
- script: |
    echo "[DEFAULT]                                                               
    host = $url
    token = $token" > ~/.databricks.cfg
```

But received this error when trying to deploy the bundle: `Error: default auth: cannot configure default credentials. Config: host=https://<databricks-host>. Env: DATABRICKS_HOST`

I also attempted the above, used my service principal client secret for the token instead of an Entra ID, this produced this error:

```
Error: Get "https://<databricks-host>/api/2.0/preview/scim/v2/Me": dial tcp: lookup <databricks-host>: no such host
```

-This almost seemed like a promising improvement, but it was very odd it could not find the host I had just used to generate an Entra ID

Last, I attempted to format the databrickcfg file for service principals (as suggested here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/authentication#--azure-service-principal-authentication).  For this I attempted:

```
      - script: |
          echo "[SP]                                                               
          host = $DATABRICKS_TARGET_HOST
          azure_tenant_id = $SP_TENANT_ID
          azure_client_id = $SP_CLIENT_ID
          azure_client_secret = $SP_CLIENT_SECRET" > /home/vsts/.databrickscfg
```

Then I attempted to force databricks to use this profile with: `databricks bundle deploy -p SP` but received `panic: config host mismatch: profile uses host ***, but CLI configured to use <databricks-host>`

In all cases, when I run `databricks auth profiles`, I am told all my profiles are `Valid=No`.  Trying to deploy without first configuring databricks also fails.

I am aware of the posted solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/ci-cd/ci-cd-github.

- This requires me to use install the Environment Variables Azure Dev Ops extension, but my organization will not approve any extensions of this kind

I am also aware of the solution involving github actions:(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/ci-cd/ci-cd-github)

- I don't want to pursue this option because I do not believe my organization will approve and I must do the bulk of my work with Azure Pipelines

What is the correct way (if one exists) to authenticate a databricks bundle deployment within an Azure pipeline yaml?

Answer (score 0):

@Lorikiki Hi,

I am not sure, but it might be the following.

Databricks CLI will prioritize environment variables (DATABRICKS_HOST, DATABRICKS_TOKEN) over the contents of the .databrickscfg file. Try the following

```
steps:
    - script: |
        echo "[DEFAULT]
        host = $(DATABRICKS_HOST)
        token = $(DATABRICKS_TOKEN)" > ~/.databrickscfg
      displayName: 'Configure .databrickscfg'
```

PS:

DATABRICKS_HOST, which represents the per-workspace URL of your Azure Databricks workspace, beginning with https://, for example https://adb-<workspace-id>.<random-number>.azuredatabricks.net. Do not include the trailing / after .net.

DATABRICKS_TOKEN, which represents your Azure Databricks [personal access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/auth#pat) or [Microsoft Entra ID token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/auth#aadt).